# Javascript inq: Controlling the number of input fields to display through javascript

Tags: javascript, upload

Script: image upload script but the focus is on the javascript.

The javascript, as of now give the user a new field to upload a image every time a the "add image" button is clicked.

Problem: The script works for most part but it gives the user unlimited upload fields.

Need:

1. control the number of times a user can click the "add image" button and if the user exceeds a set number of files to upload the "add image" button should be disable.
2. if one of the images from the list is deleted the "add image" button should be enabled again to add another image.

example:
user is allowed to upload 3 imagers.. if the user exceeds the upload the upload button is disabled. if the user del. one of the files the image upload button should be enabled to upload another file keeping with the allowed number of files to upload.

### any help you can give me would be greatly apreciated. thanks

```
    $(function()
{   $('#add-file-field').click(function()
    {   $("#addField").append('<div class="added-field"><input type="file" name="data[]"><input type="image" src="delete.png" class="remove-btn" value="Remove"></div>');
    });
    $('.remove-btn').live('click',function()
    {   $(this).parent().remove();  });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden field and put the value equal to maximum number of times you want to allow user to click the upload button. Then when user uploads the image each time you check that count from hiddenfield,

if the count is greater than zero allow user to add image and decrease the hiddenfield value count by 1.